Passing arguments to \cs_new_protected
I have a document command that uses names to set specific page widths and heights.  Now I would like to have the capability of changing the left, right, top, and bottom values from the command.  And deciding whether to use includehead and includefoot.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage {geometry}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lenest:n
  {

    \str_case:nn {#1}
      {
        {mig}
          { \geometry { paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
                         left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm,
                          includehead, includefoot } }
          }

       {nei}
         { \geometry { paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=21cm,
                        left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm,
                         includehead, includefoot } }


      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\lenest} { O{mig} }
  {
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        %% 13x21 cm
        {mig} { \lenest:n {mig} }

        %% 21x21 cm
        {nie} { \lenest:n {nei} }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%% Current implementation
\lenest {mig}

%% Desired functionality
\lenest {mig}
\lenest {mig, left=13mm, right=13mm}
\lenest {mig, top=13mm, bottom=13mm}
\lenest {mig, left=13mm, right=13mm, top=13mm, bottom=13mm}
\lenest {mig, left=13mm, right=13mm, top=13mm, bottom=13mm, excludehead}
\lenest {mig, left=13mm, right=13mm, top=13mm, bottom=13mm, excludehead, excludefoot}

\end{document}


I am open to suggestions on a convenient way to implement.  I have different page setups with different names (mig, nei, ... ) that use fixed widths and heights.

Would you not suggest using \cs_new_protected:Nn which is then called from a documunt command ?

there is no question here that I could even guess an answer to. if mig and nei are always names for those specific lengths what are the extra arguments you want to add and what should they do? You give no indication in your example about what you want to happen that is different to what the code you show does.

you just extended the example but there is no point doing the str_case twice just use \NewDocumentCommand {\lenest} {O{mig}}{\lenest:n{#1}}

Isn't this what l3keys is for?

You need to set the paper size in the preamble. You can change the margins in the document, but not with \geometry. You need \newgeometry. So the syntax you now show can't work. But note that \newgeometry will always start a new page, for obvious reasons.

I will call the command in the preamble.

Yes with l3keys in the arguments of the command.  My question related to what to include in the expl3 routine \lenest:n.

You say you want to expand to calls to \geometry but \geometry is not allowed after \begin{document} and you give no indication of how to define the keys excludehead, excludefoot
This defines keys mig and nei which set the paper width and height and pass all functionality to \geometry. The call is moved to the preamble so the underlying \geometry call does not error.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage {geometry}

\makeatletter
\define@key{Gm}{mig}[true]{%
  \Gm@defbylen{paperwidth}{13cm}%
  \Gm@defbylen{paperheight}{21cm}%
  }
\define@key{Gm}{nei}[true]{%
  \Gm@defbylen{paperwidth}{21cm}%
  \Gm@defbylen{paperheight}{21cm}%
  }
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand\lenest{}{\geometry}

                       
%% Desired functionality
\lenest {mig}
\lenest {mig, left=13mm, right=13mm}
\lenest {mig, top=13mm, bottom=13mm}
\lenest {mig, left=13mm, right=13mm, top=13mm, bottom=13mm}
\lenest {mig, left=13mm, right=13mm, top=13mm, bottom=13mm,}%? excludehead}
\lenest {mig, left=13mm, right=13mm, top=13mm, bottom=13mm,}% excludehead, excludefoot}

\begin{document}
% you can not use \geometry after \begin{document}
\end{document}


It was my mistake. I will use it before \begin{document}.

You would not make such mistakes if you actually tested your code at least %% Current implementation before posting.  @Bulldrive

I constructed it from the code I have without testing it.

@Bulldrive why waste people's time in such a way?

How can I pass variables instead of 13cm wtih \Gm@defbylen{paperwidth}{13cm}

The following defines a key=value macro that simply collects all unknown keys inside #1. Additionally we define key-shortcuts that set other keys in bulk if used. The handling of duplicate keys is completely deferred to geometry.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}
\ekvcSplit\lenest{...}{\geometry{#1}}
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\lenest
  {
    nmeta mig = {
      paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm, left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm,
      bottom=8mm, includehead, includefoot
    },
    nmeta nei = {
      paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=21cm, left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm,
      bottom=8mm, includehead, includefoot
    }
  }

\lenest{mig, left=13mm, right=13mm}

\begin{document}
\null
\end{document}


If you want the syntax \lenest{mig}, then you must declare the argument to \lenest as m, rather than O; with O you need to call \lenest[mig,<other options>].
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage[showframe,verbose]{geometry}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand {\lenest} { O{mig} }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { bulldrive/lenest } { #1 }
  \exp_args:NV \geometry \l__bulldrive_lenest_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l__bulldrive_lenest_tl

\keys_define:nn { bulldrive/lenest }
 {
  mig .code:n =
   \geometry
    {
     paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
     left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm,
     includehead, includefoot
    },
   mig .value_forbidden:n = true,
   nei .code:n =
    \geometry
     {
      paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=21cm,
      left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm,
      includehead, includefoot
     },
   nei .value_forbidden:n = true,
  unknown .code:n = \tl_put_right:Ne \l__bulldrive_lenest_tl { \l_keys_key_str = #1 , }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\lenest
%% Desired functionality
%\lenest[mig, left=13mm, right=13mm]
%\lenest[nei, top=13mm, bottom=13mm]

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}

This produces the following log from geometry:
Package geometry Warning: The marginal notes overrun the paper.
     Add 22.23781pt and more to the right margin.

*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: includehead includefoot showframe
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(22.76219pt, 324.36143pt, 22.76219pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(22.76219pt, 551.98349pt, 22.76219pt)
* \paperwidth=369.88582pt
* \paperheight=597.50787pt
* \textwidth=324.36143pt
* \textheight=484.98349pt
* \oddsidemargin=-49.5078pt
* \evensidemargin=-49.5078pt
* \topmargin=-49.5078pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=35.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

If I use the call \lenest[mig, left=13mm, right=13mm] the log says
Package geometry Warning: The marginal notes overrun the paper.
     Add 8.01143pt and more to the right margin.

*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: includehead includefoot showframe
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(36.98857pt, 295.90868pt, 36.98857pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(22.76219pt, 551.98349pt, 22.76219pt)
* \paperwidth=369.88582pt
* \paperheight=597.50787pt
* \textwidth=295.90868pt
* \textheight=484.98349pt
* \oddsidemargin=-35.28142pt
* \evensidemargin=-35.28142pt
* \topmargin=-49.5078pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=35.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

With the call \lenest[nei, top=13mm, bottom=13mm] the log says
Package geometry Warning: The marginal notes overrun the paper.
     Add 22.23781pt and more to the right margin.

*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: includehead includefoot showframe
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(22.76219pt, 551.98349pt, 22.76219pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(36.98857pt, 523.53073pt, 36.98857pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=597.50787pt
* \textwidth=551.98349pt
* \textheight=456.53073pt
* \oddsidemargin=-49.5078pt
* \evensidemargin=-49.5078pt
* \topmargin=-35.28142pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=35.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

There is no excludehead option, but you can say includehead=false and similarly for includefoot. Or you can add the keys
\keys_define:nn { bulldrive/lenest }
 {
  mig .code:n =
   \geometry
    {
     paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
     left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm,
     includehead, includefoot
    },
   mig .value_forbidden:n = true,
   nei .code:n =
    \geometry
     {
      paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=21cm,
      left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm,
      includehead, includefoot
     },
   nei .value_forbidden:n = true,
   excludehead .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nn \l__bulldrive_lenest_tl { includehead=false, },
   excludefoot .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nn \l__bulldrive_lenest_tl { includefoot=false, },
  unknown .code:n = \tl_put_right:Ne \l__bulldrive_lenest_tl { \l_keys_key_str = #1 , }
 }


I would like to use key-value variables to set values for left, right, top, bottom.  Not hardwired as I currently do.

@Bulldrive I just did like you did in the mig and nie options. Complain with yourself.

I was looking at having the capability of changing the left, right, top, and bottom values from the command using key-value pairs.
